# Using apply to replace nested for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

My goal is to go through various signals and ignore any 1's that are not part of a series (minimum of at least two 1's in a row). The data is an xts time series with 180K+ columns and 84 months. I've provided a small simplified data set I've used a nest for loop, but it's taking way too long to finish on the entire data set. It works but is horribly inefficient.

I know there's some way to use an apply function, but I can't figure it out.

Example data:

```
    mod_sig <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1), 
                          b = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1), 
                          c = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0), 
                          d = c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
                          e = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))

    mod_sig <- xts(mod_sig, order.by = as.Date(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2017-02-01"), by = "month")))
```

Example code:

```
   # fixing months where condition is only met for one month
   # creating a new data frame for modified signals
   Signals_Fin <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(mod_sig), ncol = ncol(mod_sig)))
   colnames(Signals_Fin) <- colnames(mod_sig)

   # Loop over Signals to change 1's to 0's for one month events
   for(col in 1:ncol(mod_sig)) {
     for(row in 1:nrow(mod_sig)) {
       val <- ifelse(mod_sig[row,col] == 1, 
                     ifelse(mod_sig[row-1,col] == 0, 
                            ifelse(mod_sig[row+1,col] == 0,0,1),1),0)
       Signals_Fin[row, col] <- val
     }
   }
```

As you can see with the loop, any 1's that aren't in a sequence are changed to 0's. I know there is a better way, so I'm hoping to improve my approach. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer from Zack and Ryan:

Zack and Ryan were spot on with dyplr, I only made slight modifications based off what was given and some colleague help.

Answer code:

```
    mod_sig <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1), 
                      b = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1), 
                      c = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0), 
                      d = c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
                      e = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))

    Signals_fin = mod_sig %>% 
                  mutate_all(funs(ifelse((. == 1 & (lag(.) == 1 | lead(.) == 1)),1,0))) %>% 
                  mutate_all(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))


    Signals_fin <- xts(Signals_fin, order.by = as.Date(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2017-02-01"), by = "month")))
```

Comment: Apply is as slow as any loop. The solution here is to loop over a matrix and not a data.frame. The speed increase exponentially

Comment: Or an alternative can be provided by an elegant data.table solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, looks like Zach and Ryan were spot on with dyplr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a stab from a `dplyr` perspective, I converted your row_names to a column but you can just as easily convert them back to rownames with `tibble::column_to_rownames()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mod_sig %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column('months') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-months), function(x){
    if_else(x == 1 & 
              (lag(x, order_by = .$months) == 1 | 
                 lead(x, order_by = .$months) == 1),
            1,
            0)
  })
```

As suggested by @Ryan, his `mutate_at` call is more elegant, it's important everything is already sorted, though:

```
mod_sig %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column('months') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-months),  ~ as.numeric(.x & (lag(.x) | lead(.x))))
```

And to build on his suggestion:

```
mod_sig %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate_all(~ as.numeric(.x & (lag(.x) | lead(.x))))
```

Comment: This is great, dyplr was definetly the way to go. I ended up using basically what you had, with minor revisions. Thanks again!